# Django view doesn't output correctly

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view which should output if the domain on the database is online or offline.

```
def pingDomain(request, page):
    page_object = get_object_or_404(Table, page=page)
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c', '1',  page_object.page])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        host_online = True
    else:
        host_online = False
    context = {
        'online': host_online,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

On the html template

```
<th class="center-align red-text text-darken-4" scope="row">
    {% if online %}
      <i class="small material-icons green-text">check_circle</i>
    {% else %}
      <i class="small material-icons red-text">close</i>
    {% endif %}
</th>
```

The problem is, on the html template, it shows that the domains are offline but are actually online.

Where did I make a mistake? Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: What is your `subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c', '1',  page_object.page])` result?

Comment: Nothing's on the console

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to achieve is the following:

```py
def pingDomain(request, page):
    page_object = get_object_or_404(Table, page=page)
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-c', '1',  page_object.page])
        host_online = True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        host_online = False

    context = {
        'online': host_online,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Reason being I've changed your logic is because if the `subprocess` raises an error you want to set the `host_online = False` and not the opposite

Comment: Still showing the domains are offline after changing my code to your answer

Comment: Can you check now, please?

Comment: This is the template output. The red ones should be green if the domains are online and red if otherwise https://highcenburg.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/template-view.png

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you have in `page_object.page`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201274/discussion-between-highcenburg-and-higor-rossato).

Comment: page = models.URLField(verbose_name=None)

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you simply get your variable values backwards? You're setting `host_online` to `True`, on an exception of the ping call, that doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Hmmm I just changed them but still outputs the domains are offline